# Merge two dictionary in python with different keys

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict_conv
Out[162]: 
{'Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism': 4,
 'Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism': 4,
 'Benzoate degradation': 6,
 'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': 16}

dict_org
Out[163]: 
{'Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism': 5,
 'Arginine and proline metabolism': 4,
 'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': 11,
 'Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites': 21}
```

and I want to combine them.
I did like this:

```
def mergeDict(dict_conv, dict_org):
   ''' Merge dictionaries and keep values of common keys in list'''
   dict3 = {**dict_conv, **dict_org}
   for key, value in dict3.items():
       if key in dict_conv and key in dict_org:
               dict3[key] = [value , dict_conv[key]]
   return dict3

dict3 = mergeDict(dict_conv, dict_org)
```

and got this dict:

```
dict3
Out[164]: 
{'Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism': 4,
 'Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism': 4,
 'Benzoate degradation': 6,
 'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': [11, 16],
 'Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites': [21, 26]}
```

I want to have two values (in a list) **for every key**.
If the key is not in one of the dictionaries I want it to write 0, like this:

```
dict3
    Out[164]: 
    {'Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism': [4,0],
     'Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism': [0,5],
     'Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism': [4,0],
     'Benzoate degradation': [6,0],
     'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': [11, 16],
     'Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites': [0,21]}
```

(the first value represent the "dict_conv" value, and the second represent the "dict_org" value)

what should I add to the `mergeDict` function?

thank you :)

Comment: Your example is inconsistent.  Input does not contain 26 yet your output does.  Does the order of the two values matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply build a set of all keys, then create the lists using the `get` method of the dicts, with a default value of 0:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    keys = set(d1.keys()) | set(d2.keys())
    return {key: [d1.get(key, 0), d2.get(key, 0)] for key in keys}
```

As suggested by @Stephan B, the first line can be written in a shorter way:

```
keys = set(d1) | set(d2)
```

because iterating on a dict iterates on its keys, or as:

```
keys = set(d1).union(d2)
```

because the argument to `union`, `intersection` and so on only needs to be an iterable, not necessarily a set.

Sample run with your data:

```
d1 = {'Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism': 4,
     'Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism': 4,
     'Benzoate degradation': 6,
     'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': 16}

d2 = {'Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism': 5,
     'Arginine and proline metabolism': 4,
     'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': 11,
     'Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites': 21}

print(merge(d1, d2))
```

Output:

```
{'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': [16, 11], 
'Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism': [0, 5], 
'Arginine and proline metabolism': [0, 4], 
'Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism': [4, 0], 
'Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism': [4, 0], 
'Benzoate degradation': [6, 0], 
'Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites': [0, 21]}
```

Comment: don't even need the `.keys()`: `set(d1) | set(d2)` or `set(d1).union(d2)` is sufficient/faster

Comment: @StefanB Right, I added the suggestions and a bit of explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set the value unconditionally with:

```
from pprint import pprint

...

for key in dict3.keys():
    dict3[key] = [dict_conv.get(key, 0), dict_org.get(key, 0)]
....

pprint(dict3)
{'Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism': [4, 0],
 'Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism': [0, 5],
 'Arginine and proline metabolism': [0, 4],
 'Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism': [4, 0],
 'Benzoate degradation': [6, 0],
 'Biosynthesis of antibiotics': [16, 11],
 'Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites': [0, 21]}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with example output.  Not sure why you get something different.

Comment: My bad, I had messed the indentation while copying your code in the original one. I get the same output as you, but this is still not what is expected: for `'Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism'`, you should get `[0, 5]`, as the value `5` comes from the second dict, not `[5, 0]`.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't clear if order matter.  Fixed.  The next step is to eliminate dict3 which is what @Thierry Lathuille's solution does.